# How can I see the original form of an edited hunk?

Tags: git, diff, git-add

`git add -p` is handy to stage only parts of the uncommitted work. Usually, it's just a matter of confirming/denying whether some individual hunks should go in the commit. However, sometimes I need to split up a hunk finer than the <kbd>s</kbd> option will go.

Enter <kbd>e</kbd>, which opens an editor in which the diff can be changed al gusto.

Unfortunately, I often get this wrong so when I'm done git says

```
error: patch failed: src/foo.bar:1234
error: src/foo.bar: patch does not apply
```

It offers me to re-open the hunk again, but there it's hard to see how the diff originally looked / how it would need to look, in order to apply.

Is there some easy way to see this, without going back and doing `git add -p` completely anew?

Answer (score 0):

If your patch does not apply, you should see this line

```
Your edited hunk does not apply. Edit again (saying "no" discards!) [y/n]?
```

Then it is as simple as pressing <kbd>n</kbd> and then pressing <kbd>k</kbd> (to go back "see previous undecided hunk")

I will search for a nice article explaining how to edit hunks correctly and post the link here.

---

#### Update (2018-01-17):

The git documentation has a nice section about [**Advanced Merging**](https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-Tools-Advanced-Merging#_manual_remerge) and in there you can find **Manual File Re-merging** which states:

> First, we get into the merge conflict state. Then we want to get copies of my version of the file, their version (from the branch we’re merging in) and the common version (from where both sides branched off). Then we want to fix up either their side or our side and re-try the merge again for just this single file.
>
> Getting the three file versions is actually pretty easy. Git stores all of these versions in the index under “stages” which each have numbers associated with them. Stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is your version and stage 3 is from the MERGE_HEAD, the version you’re merging in (“theirs”).
>
> You can extract a copy of each of these versions of the conflicted file with the git show command and a special syntax.
>
> ```
> $ git show :1:hello.rb > hello.common.rb
> $ git show :2:hello.rb > hello.ours.rb
> $ git show :3:hello.rb > hello.theirs.rb
> ```

Does this help?